# Mongodb $where query always true with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I query my database with a function passed in the "$where" clause in nodejs, it always return me all documents in the db.

For example, if I do

```
var stream = timetables.find({$where: function() { return false; }}).stream();
```

it return me all the documents.
Instead, if I do

```
var stream = timetables.find({$where: 'function() { return false; }'}).stream();
```

the function is really executed, and this code doesn't return any document.

The problem is that if I convert in string my function the context's bindinds are removed, and I need them for more complex query. For example:

```
var n = 1;
var f = function() { return this.number == n; }
var stream = timetables.find({$where: f.toString()}).stream();
// error: n is not defined
```

Is this a normal behaviour? How can I solve my problem?
Please excuse me for my poor english!

Comment: While it could be cool if that would work the way you suggested, it won't. What type of query do you want? Using `$where` is normally considered to be a last resort option due to the way it executes and resulting performance. Read this (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, keep in mind that the `$where` operator should almost never be used for the reasons explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/) (credit goes to @WiredPrairie).

Back to your issue, the approach you'd like to take won't work even in the mongodb shell (which explicitly allows naked js functions with the `$where` operator). The javascript code provided to the `$where` operator is executed on the mongo server and won't have access to the enclosing environment (the "context bindings").

```
> db.test.insert({a: 42})
> db.test.find({a: 42})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5150433c73f604984a7dff91"), "a" : 42 }
> db.test.find({$where: function() { return this.a == 42 }}) // works
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5150433c73f604984a7dff91"), "a" : 42 }
> var local_var = 42
> db.test.find({$where: function() { return this.a == local_var }})
error: {
    "$err" : "error on invocation of $where function:\nJS Error: ReferenceError: local_var is not defined nofile_b:1",
    "code" : 10071
}
```

Moreover it looks like that the node.js native mongo driver behaves differently from the shell in that it doesn't automatically serialize a js function you provide in the query object and instead it likely drops the clause altogether. This will leave you with the equivalent of `timetables.find({})` which will return all the documents in the collection.

Comment: > db.test.find({$where: function() { return this.a == 42 }})

you can't use above code,when the value of 42 is Dynamic.

Still get same error while using this one.

Answer (score 4):

This one is works for me , Just try to store a query as a string in one variable then concat your variable in query string,

> var local_var = 42
>
> var query = "{$where: function() { return this.a == "+local_var+"}}"
>
> db.test.find(query)

Comment: You can also use string interpolation : `var query = {$where: \`function() { return this.a == ${local_var}}\`}`

Answer (score 2):

Store your query into a varibale and use that variable at your find query. It works..... :D

Answer (score 1):

The context will always be that of the mongo database, since the function is executed there. There is no way to share the context between the two instances. You have to rethink the way you query and come up with a different strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper to pass basic JSON objects, ie. (pardon coffee-script):

```coffee
# That's the main wrapper.
wrap = (f, args...) ->
  "function() { return (#{f}).apply(this, #{JSON.stringify(args)}) }"

# Example 1
where1 = (flag) ->
  @myattr == 'foo' or flag

# Example 2 with different arguments
where2 = (foo, options = {}) ->
  if foo == options.bar or @_id % 2 == 0
    true
  else
    false

db.collection('coll1').count $where: wrap(where1, true), (err, count) ->
  console.log err, count

db.collection('coll1').count $where: wrap(where2, true, bar: true), (err, count) ->
  console.log err, count
```

Your functions are going to be passed as something like:

```coffee
function () {
    return (function (flag) {
        return this.myattr === 'foo' || flag;
    }).apply(this, [true])
}
```

...and example 2:

```coffee
function () {
    return (
        function (foo, options) {
            if (options == null) {
                options = {};
            }
            if (foo === options.bar || this._id % 2 === 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    ).apply(this, [ true, { "bar": true } ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is supposed to be. The drivers don't translate the client code into the mongo function javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to query your database.

If you take a look at the actual Query object implementation, you'll find that only *strings* are valid arguments for the [where prototype](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L575).

When using the where clause, you should use it along with the standard operators such as gt, lt that operates on in the path created by the where function.

Remember that Mongoose querying, as in Mongo, is by example, you may want to reconsider your query specification in a more descriptive fashion.