# Passing a parameter in $where with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, where-clause

I've a little problem with my script. I cannot passing a parameter (MYPARAMETER  in the example) in the function in the '$where'.

You have an idea for help me ? Thanks.

```
var MYPARAMETER = "dqsd qsdqs &é&é";

MyCol.findOne({

    $where: function(MYPARAMETER) 
    { 
        var tab1="ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ!#$€%&'`(),;:/@.*[]\|";
        var tab2=   "aaaaaaaaaaaaooooooooooooeeeeeeeecciiiiiiiiuuuuuuuuynn                      ";
        rep2=tab1.split('');
        rep=tab2.split('');
        parray=new Array();
        var i=-1;
        while(rep2[++i])
        {
            parray[rep2[i]]=rep[i]
        }
        var chaine = this.name.replace(/\s{1,}/g,"-");
        chaine = chaine.replace(/./g, function($0){return (parray[$0])?parray[$0]:$0 });
        chaine = chaine.replace(/\s/g,"");


        return (chaine == MYPARAMETER);
    }
},
```

Comment: did you managed to find the solution for this except including the variable directly in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `$where` executes on the server, and thus wouldn't have access to a variable that was locally declared on another server. JavaScript should be used as a [last resort generally in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), and this appears to go the other way and perform a LOT of very time consuming work.

You'd need to build the function as a string and include the value directly.

Answer (score 1):

To use variables in **$where** query, first create mongo query as a string and then parse string to **JSON** when passing as parameter

Example:

```
var query = '{"$where": "function() { return (\'' + address + '\').indexOf(this.city) >= 0 }"}';
db.city.find(JSON.parse(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is works for me , Just try to store a query as a string in one variable then concat your variable in query string,

> var local_var = 42
>
> var query = "{$where: function() { return this.a == "+local_var+"}}"
>
> db.test.find(query)

[watch the reference exaple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958916/4251085)

Answer (score 0):

> Use the $where operator to pass either a string containing a
> JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query
> system.

To pass a variable just create a string containing your local data like this (You don't need to parse it):

```
const myLocalVar = "test"    

const $where =  `function() { 
                return this.template.indexOf('${myLocalVar}')>=0
            }`

db.collection.find({$where})
```