# Mongo not behaving according to docs, with regards to implicit $where clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The following code works:

```
collection.find({ $where: "this.primary_photo === 'bar'" }).toArray( (err, documents) => {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log('documents:::', documents)
})
```

But the following doesn't:

```
collection.find("this.primary_photo === 'bar'").toArray( (err, documents) => {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log('documents:::', documents)
})
```

According to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/:

> if the query consists only of the $where operator, you can pass in
>   just the JavaScript expression or JavaScript functions, as in the
>   following examples:
>
> db.myCollection.find( "this.credits == this.debits || this.credits >
>   this.debits" );
>
> db.myCollection.find( function() { return (this.credits == this.debits
>   || this.credits > this.debits ) } );

Why is my implementation failing?

I'm getting the following error when I pass just the string:

```
MongoError: query selector must be an object
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/pierre/Desktop/spysmiles.com/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at Collection.find (/home/pierre/Desktop/spysmiles.com/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:313:22)
    at MongoClient.connect (/home/pierre/Desktop/spysmiles.com/tools/sst/commands/image/delete.js:28:16)
    at connectCallback (/home/pierre/Desktop/spysmiles.com/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at /home/pierre/Desktop/spysmiles.com/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:347:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I'm using the Node.js driver and running this query from within a node script.

Comment: Why are you using `$where` at all? This is a simple query for native operators `{ "primary_photo": "bar" }`. The documentation here is actually misleading since the particular code block example you are focusing on is only valid in the "mongo shell". In fact even the shortened `function()` direct usage in `.find()` is of course not supported outside of any other language than JavaScript. In just about every driver, the supported form is essentially *"A JavaScript function or expression that returns boolean represented as a string"* in pair with a `$where` key. That the supported way.

Comment: In short. You misinterpreted the documentation. But the documentation "should" be clearer on this.

Comment: I was trying to use a more complicated $where query but boiled it down to what i posted and found not even that to be working as expected.  So, are you saying the $where operator works, but not the shortened function () direct usage, when using it from the driver?  Is the documentation i referenced meant for the shell?

Comment: **Most** of the operator syntax is a general translation which applies to all language implementations. But the specific `.find("true")` ( as the essence of any expression ) in this case only applies to the shell where it treats an input of a string as being an implied `$where`. The drivers themselves do not honor that rule and outside of JavaScript it would not be possible in most languages. At any rate 90% cases where you think you need an expression can usually be applied with operators. And of the remaining, 90% of those can be applied with `.aggregate()` and `$redact` which is faster.

Comment: To be really breif, the node driver definition for [`.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) is actually says `query : object` which implies just a plain "object" as opposed to a "string" for an argument. Which is again slightly misleading since that documentation makes no reference to optional "projection" or "callback" parameters which are also valid.

Comment: Also quoting the [mongojs README](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) *"...emulates the official mongodb API as much as possible. It wraps mongodb-native"* Which means it only really does what the underlying driver does and then only *".. as much as possible .."* since there are some limits as to what can be applied. So "works as designed".

Comment: I'm totally mistaken.  I'm not using mongojs, I'm using the official mongodb driver for node.js https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native.  Sorry about that, i need to change that from the question.  But what you said sounds like it could still apply, no?

Comment: Yes it still applies. I also linked to the `.find()` method documentation from the base nodejs driver above. So the issue is essentially that you cannot simply supply an expression as a "string" in an argument to `.find()`, and this can only be done in the mongo shell. I'm actually submitting a documentation patch request for this today, since as you have demonstrated it is misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Neil Lunn's comments, I was able to determine that the documentation I was viewing was actually for the mongo shell.  The reason it was confusing is because the `$where` operator takes javascript (and executes it on the mongo server), which I believed it was showing in the docs because it was demonstrating the node.js *driver*.  Turns out Mongo understands javascript natively...

I also found the following question and answers helpful: [Mongodb $where query always true with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612947/mongodb-where-query-always-true-with-nodejs).

In short - You can use the `$where` operator using the node.js driver, but you have to pass it explicitly as an object (`{$where: 'function(){}'}`), and the function has to be passed as a string, otherwise mongo just gives you back all documents (see linked question above).